# How can I change the GTK engine on Cinnamon >= 2.0?

Tags: gtk, cinnamon

I just upgraded to Cinnamon 2.0.14 on my [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) laptop and in this new version I am unable to change the GTK engine used. Menus and widgets in general look very ugly:

[image]

When they should look something like this:

[image]

In principle, I should be able to change this using Cinnamon's own settings app in System Settings => Themes => Other Settings => Controls:

[image]

However, while most options available in that window work (Window Borders for example), the "Controls" and "Icons" options are ignored.

Starting from version 2.0, Cinnamon has become independent of Gnome and in fact conflicts with it. I have therefore had to remove Gnome to install this version of Cinnamon which may be relevant. I do have the necessary GTK packages installed though:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep engines | grep gtk | awk '{printf "%s  %-26s %-22s\n",$1,$2,$3}'
ii  gtk2-engines:amd64         1:2.20.2-3            
ii  gtk2-engines-aurora        1.5.1-3               
ii  gtk2-engines-candido       0.9.1-pablo4          
ii  gtk2-engines-magicchicken  1.1.1-9               
ii  gtk2-engines-moblin        1.1.1-1.1             
ii  gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 0.98.1.1-5            
ii  gtk2-engines-nodoka        0.7.0-1.2             
ii  gtk2-engines-oxygen:amd64  1.3.3-2               
ii  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:amd64  2.24.20-1             
ii  gtk2-engines-wonderland    1.0-8                 
ii  gtk2-engines-xfce          3.0.1-2               
ii  gtk3-engines-oxygen:amd64  1.1.4-1               
ii  gtk3-engines-unico:amd64   1.0.2-1
```

So, how can I choose the GTK engine used by Cinnamon to make my new desktop pretty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these issues came because I was using a private repository linked to `sid` as described [here](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/10/how-to-build-and-install-the-latest-cinnamon-from-git/#comment-3632). Turns out I had only upgraded part of cinnamon and its dependencies and my problems were fixed by pointing my `sources.list` to the Debian sid repos and running

```
sudo apt-get install gtk3-engines-*
```

I can now change the appearance of my desktop as required. In the process, I came across a nifty little program called `lxappearance` that is similar to `gtk-chtheme` but gives more options. I highly recommend it, it is in the Debian repos and can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install lxappearance
```

Answer (score 3):

> how can I choose the GTK engine used by Cinnamon to make my new desktop pretty?

WRT **GTK 2**: Try installing `gtk-chtheme`.  This is an independent application:

[image: gtk-chtheme screenshot]

I don't use Cinnamon (or Mint) but this has never failed to override a DE's settings for me.

These settings are (I presume) universally kept in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, but being able to browse the themes graphically makes things a little simpler.

Comment: Ah, great tool, thanks and +1. That seems to work for some programs (`firefox` for example) but not for others (like `nemo`, the file manager). I am guessing this might be a GTK2 vs GTK3 issue. I know that `nemo` uses GTK3, any way of changing the GTK3 engine?

Comment: I don't know of anything that parallels this, but I think the parallel config file is probably `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` -- you could try editing that and restarting Cinnamon. :\

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out and am trying to tweak it now. There's some useful info (as always) on the arch wiki [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B#GTK.2B_3.x) on GTK+.